# equality operator with tuple: 'a', 'b' == ('a', 'b')

Tags: python, tuples

A tuple can be made without parenthesis.

```
t1 = 'a', 'b'
t2 = ('a', 'b')
t1 == t2
```

Output:

```
True
```

But when tried this

```
'a', 'b' == ('a', 'b')
```

Output:

```
('a', False)
```

Can someone explain the Output in the second part?

Comment: you created a tuple. False is the result of evaluating the second part

Comment: Order of operations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`,` as a tuple operator has **extremely** low precedence. This means that if you don't put parentheses, it will be one of the last operators to be grouped. So, `'a', 'b' == ('a', 'b')` is **not** `('a', 'b') == ('a', 'b')`, but rather `'a', ('b' == ('a', 'b'))`.

Answer (score 3):

The comparison `'b' == ('a', 'b')` is evaluated before `,`, so the result is

```
'a', ('b' == ('a', 'b'))
('a', False)
```